# Route53 ドメイン登録が失敗した場合の対処法

Tags: amazon-route53

先日、Route53のドメイン登録を行ったところ、以下のようなメールが来て失敗してしまいました。

> We weren't able to register the domain name. This is because:
> Parameters in request are not valid

特にこれといって特別なことはしておらず、普通に注文しただけです。
いまだに失敗している状態で、請求だけ来ているので困っています。
同じ状況になったことのある方、ご教示いただけますと助かります。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[AWS をご利用のすべてのお客様にベーシックサポートプランを無料でご利用いただけます。このプランには、ドメイン登録に関連する以下の問題のサポートが含まれています。](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-contact-support.html)

とのことなので、問い合わせればいいのでは？

Comment: わざわざリンクをありがとうございます！
確かに仰る通りです…
すぐ問い合わせます！